# Connect Windows 8 app to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-8.1

I am making my first Windows 8 app using C#. I have a MySQL Database that I would like to connect to. I have done this before with windows forms and everything went smoothly. However with the windows 8 app it won't connect.

This is my connection string:

```
string myConnectionString = "Server=mysql9.000webhost.com; Database=a2236339_snooker; Uid=a2236339_joe; password=TeamPr0ject;";
```

The code looks like:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
connection.Open();
```

and then open my connection like that.

The error that I get is

> An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.RT.DLL but was not handled in user code

Can anyone explain why this is and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: My first step in troubleshooting would be to handle the exception and see what the error is.  Put a try/catch block around it.  Put a break point in the catch block so when the exception is caught, you can see the details in the debugger.

Comment: After the try catch it says "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts" I have double checked the connection string and all seems to be correct

Comment: If you search for that string in SO or Google there will be dozens hits.  The first one that I looked at was that it didn't like the DNS name and using the IP address worked.  You may want to try that.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see the rest of your code but if I was doing a connection the correct way I will do it is:

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=YOUR_SERVER;database=YOUR_DATABASE;uid=YOUR_USERNAME;password=YOUR_PASSWORD;"))
{
     connection.Open();
     MySqlCommand userinfoCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT name, FROM table",connection);

     using (MySqlDataReader reader = userinfoCommand.ExecuteReader())
     {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
               String name= reader.GetString("name");
          }

          connection.Close();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=YOUR_SERVER;database=YOUR_DATABASE;uid=YOUR_USERNAME;password=YOUR_PASSWORD;"))
{
     connection.Open();
     MySqlCommand userinfoCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT name, FROM table",connection);

     using (MySqlDataReader reader = userinfoCommand.ExecuteReader())
     {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
               String name= reader.GetString("name");
          }

          connection.Close();
     }
}
```