# How to connect W10 Universal App with MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, win-universal-app

I'm writing my first Windows 10 Universal App that operates on MySql database. I used code from this guide (It's for Windows 8 store apps):

https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/how_to_using_connector_net

But when I try to open connection with my database I get error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in >MySql.Data.RT.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: SSL not supported in this WinRT release.

```
public class DBconnector
{
    static string server = "127.0.0.1";
    static string database = "hurtownia";
    static string user = "root";
    static string pswd = "root";

    public static bool login(string email, string password)
    {
        string connectionString = "Server = " + server + ";database = " + database + ";uid = " + user + ";password = " + pswd + ";";
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand checkLogin = new MySqlCommand("select password_hash, password_salt from users where email = \""+email+"\"",connection);
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = checkLogin.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                string hash = reader.GetString("password_hash");
                string salt = reader.GetString("password_salt");

                bool result = passwordGenerator.compare(password, hash, salt);

                if (result)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, my question is how to fix that and correctly connect to MySql database in Windows 10 Universal App.

Comment: have you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462441/connect-windows-8-app-to-mysql

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add ";SslMode=None" to your connection string

Comment: It really surprises me that they would make SSL the default mode, considering that their binary distributions don't support SSL/TLS.  You  have to build from source to get SSL/TLS support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afarid the SSL connection is not supported by MySql WinRT connector. You have to disable the SSL connection from the MySql server.

[Chapter 8 Connector/Net Support for Windows Store](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-rt.html)

> Connector/Net RT does not support SSL connections or Windows
>   authentication. Also, SHA256 is not currectly supported.

[6.3.6.4 SSL Command Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ssl-options.html#option_general_ssl)

BTW, another alternative way to retrieve the data from mysql is host a REST service:
App -> Rest Service -> MySQL

Comment: I have disabled SSL in MySQL Workbench: http://i.imgur.com/blyX30t.png
I also added line skip-ssl in my.ini file and I still have this error.