# Connect to SQL Database on Server (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, uwp

I'm developing an App for Windows 10.

I have SQL Database on my Server and I need to connect using IP (https://144.76.133.122:1500/myadmin/)

I try to use this code

```
private SqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password;

    // Constructor
    public DbConnect()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    // Initialize values
    private void Initialize()
    {
        server = "";
        database = "rent";
        uid = "root";
        password = "password123";
        string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
                                  database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
```

But I don't have a reference for `SqlConnection`

How I can connect to my database?

Comment: Can you clarify: `But I have no reference for SqlConnection`?

Comment: I try to add reference System.Data.SqlClient, but I don't see it in Reference Manager @FrankerZ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect W10 Universal App with MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442056/how-to-connect-w10-universal-app-with-mysql-database)